# Location of .htaccess and httpd.conf files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, optimization

I am trying to use leverage browser caching option in order to increase  google page speed rank. For that purpose i need to add following code to `.htaccess` file or in `httpd.conf` file on apache server:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"


ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”


ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

But i dont know where to find .htaccess and httpd.conf file. Can anybody tell where i will find these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` files are in any web directory, and you may need to enable visibility of dot-files to read them (`.htaccess` is considered a dot-file since it begins with a `.`).

To find the location of `httpd.conf`, use this link:

[DistrosDefaultLayout - Httpd Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout)